# react I get an error when trying to add a new post with a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react app like a blog I have a home page with all my posts displayed when you click on a post it takes to a detail page with comments and a button that opens a modal to add a comment. 
I am trying to add a button on my home page to add a new post but I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.props.postNewPost is not a function
NewPostForm.handleNewPost
D:/Documents/job_application/tasks/interfell/src/components/MenuComponent.js:98
 95 | handleNewPost(values){
 96 |     console.log("Current state: "+JSON.stringify(values));
 97 |     this.toggleNewPost();
>  98 |     this.props.postNewPost( values.userId, values.title, values.body);
  | ^   99 | }
 100 | 
 101 |  render() {
```

This is my Menu or Home component

```
import React,{Component}  from 'react';
import { Button,Modal,ModalBody,ModalHeader,Row,Label} from 'reactstrap';
import { Control, LocalForm, Errors } from 'react-redux-form';


import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';


    function RenderMenuItem({post , onClick, postNewPost }){
        return(
                <Link to={`/menu/${post.id}`} >
                   <Grid xs={12}>
                     <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                     <p>{post.body}</p>
                   </Grid>
                </Link>

        );
    }

    function RenderPost({postNewPost }){
        return(
                <>
                    <NewPostForm postNewPost={postNewPost} />
                    </>
        );
    }



    const Menu = (props) => {
        const menu = props.posts.posts.map((post) => {
            return (
              <Grid key={post.id} xs={12}>
                <RenderMenuItem post={post} />
              </Grid>
            );
        });

        if(props.posts.isLoading){
            return(
                <Grid container >
                        <Loading />
                </Grid>
            );
        }
        else if (props.posts.errMess){
            return(
                <Grid container >
                <Grid xs={12} >
                        <h4>{props.posts.errMess}</h4>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            );
        }
        else{
            return(
                <Grid container >
                        <Grid xs={6}>
                            <h3>Posts</h3>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid xs={6}>
                            <RenderPost  />
                        </Grid>
                <Grid>
                  {menu}
               </Grid>
                </Grid>
            );
        }
    }

    const minLength = (len) => (val) => (val) && (val.length >= len );
    const maxLength = (len) => (val) => !(val) || (val.length <= len );

    class NewPostForm extends Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                isNewPostOpen:false
            }
            this.toggleNewPost = this.toggleNewPost.bind(this);
            this.handleNewPost = this.handleNewPost.bind(this);
        }

        toggleNewPost(){
            this.setState({
                isNewPostOpen : !this.state.isNewPostOpen
            });
        }

        handleNewPost(values){
            console.log("Current state: "+JSON.stringify(values));
            this.toggleNewPost();
            this.props.postNewPost( values.userId, values.title, values.body);
        }

         render() {
             return(
                 <>
                     <Button outline onClick={this.toggleNewPost}>
                         <span className="fa fa-pencil fa-lg">Add Post</span>
                     </Button>
                     <Modal isOpen={this.state.isNewPostOpen} toggle={this.toggleNewPost}>
                         <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleNewPost}>Submit Comment</ModalHeader>
                         <ModalBody>
                             <LocalForm className="container" onSubmit={(values)=>this.handleNewPost(values)}>


                                  <Grid md={12}>
                                      <Label htmlFor="userId">Your User Id</Label>
                                      <Control.text model=".userId" id="userId" name="userId" className="form-control" placeholder="Your userId"validators={{ minLength:minLength(1),maxLength:maxLength(15) }} />
                                      <Errors className="text-danger" model=".userId" show="touched" messages={{
                                              minLength:'At least 3 characters',
                                              maxLength:'Must be 15 characters or less'
                                          }} />
                                  </Grid> <Grid md={12}>
                                      <Label htmlFor="title">Post title</Label>
                                      <Control.text model=".title" id="title" name="title" className="form-control" placeholder="Post title"validators={{ minLength:minLength(3) }} />


                                  </Grid>
                                  <Grid className="form-group" md={12}>
                                      <Label htmlFor="body"> Comment</Label>
                                      <Control.textarea model=".body" id="body" name="body" rows="6" className="form-control"/>
                                  </Grid>
                                  <Grid className="form-group" md={12}>
                                      <Button type="submit" color="primary">Submit</Button>
                                  </Grid>
                             </LocalForm>
                         </ModalBody>
                     </Modal>
                 </>
                );
        }
    }

export default Menu;
```

I am new to react and I am a bit lost. Sorry for it being in material UI and bootstrap I am trying to convert it from bootstrap to material UI

Comment: You are not passing in any prop into `<RenderPost  />` which in passing it down to `<NewPostForm />`. As long as you are passing the prop into `<Menu />` this should fix your problem

Comment: I tried editing <RenderPost /> like this 
       <RenderPost  postNewPost={props.postNewPost}/> but still get the same error

Comment: `<RenderPost />` takes a prop called `postNewPost`. Do you have a sandbox with this in?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-night-5cdej I created a sandbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to propagate your function `postNewPost` from your `<MainComponent />`.

```
return (
  <div>
    <TransitionGroup>
        <CSSTransition key={this.props.location.key} classNames="page" timeout={300}>
        <Switch location={this.props.location} >
               // You are not passing the prop into <Menu /> here
                <Route exact path="/menu" component={() => <Menu posts={this.props.posts} /> } />
                <Route path="/menu/:postId" component={PostWithId} />
                <Redirect to="/menu" />
            </Switch>
        </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  </div>
);
```

That line needs to be:

```
<Route exact path="/menu" component={() => <Menu posts={this.props.posts} postNewPost={this.props.postNewPost} /> } />
```

From there, your `<Menu />` component is propagating the component correctly.

I suggest using the `prop-types` library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

It will give you helpful warning messages if your components are missing required props or getting incorrect props.

Comment: I used the code you gave me but I get this error now TypeError: Cannot read property 'posts' of undefined

Comment: That looks like it depends on the kind of data structure you are receiving. I suggest you implement `prop-types` on your components to see if it can help you debug. This will aid you if you run into any problems in the future.

Comment: Ok I am not getting the error anymore but the new post is not getting added to the posts on the home page

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this`

In your constructor in NewPostForm, do `this.handleNewPost = this.handleNewPost.bind(this);`

You can use this to help you with that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autobind

Comment: I allready have this in my constructor this.handleNewPost = this.handleNewPost.bind(this);